# Angular 7 is failing on create

Tags: node-modules, angular7

All of a sudden when I go to create a new app. I'm getting a build fail error, and I notice no node_modules were installed. Everything used to work.

I reinstalled Angular CLI and Visual Studio. Now there is no option for SCSS, and when I pick the leftover stylesheets I get `Could not find (undefined)`.

Here is my create error

```
CREATE myapp-build/e2e/src/app.po.ts (251 bytes)
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @angular/compiler@~7.2.0 (sha512-GXdvgH8oxK8HRh/FelN3U5p0tsTUwGh8b/iuuJKaunBSSDDjIy7pPnn3zT+lN4YeEi6qN1XWudt+HpWHYHyymg==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Floor 15\Code\myapp-build\node_modules\.staging\@angular\compiler-6990c845\src\expression_parser\parser.js
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Floor 15\Code\myapp-build\node_modules\.staging\@angular\compiler-6990c845\src\expression_parser\parser.js'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Floor 15\Code\myapp-build\node_modules\.staging\@angular\compiler-6990c845\src\expression_parser\parser.js'
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Floor 15\Code\myapp-build\node_modules\.staging\@angular\compiler-6990c845\src\expression_parser\parser.js'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!      path: 'C:\\Users\\Floor 15\\Code\\myapp-build\\node_modules\\.staging\\@angular\\compiler-6990c845\\src\\expression_parser\\parser.js' },
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\\Users\\Floor 15\\Code\\myapp-build\\node_modules\\.staging\\@angular\\compiler-6990c845\\src\\expression_parser\\parser.js\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Floor 15\\Code\\myapp-build\\node_modules\\.staging\\@angular\\compiler-6990c845\\src\\expression_parser\\parser.js',
npm ERR!   parent: 'myapp-build' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Floor 15\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-20T23_06_56_831Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Do have the package.json file opened? Or Visual Studio with the project? Try closing that if so.

Comment: Very strange I was getting error in Visual Studio. I created in cmd prompt and it worked. I'm still not getting the Scss option, which really bugs me. I guess my next question would be why doesn't this work in my visual studio terminal? Ng serve and build in vs terminal works.SMH...